# Using a URL query string variable in a Wordpress page or post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to access and use a variable passed in the URL within a WordPress page  (not a template file, but the page itself).

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to create a single page that will display different WP content by using text passed in the URL in shortcodes and elsewhere on the page.  So, if the URL was specified as:

`www.greenneedham.org/blog/topicpage/?topic=solar`

I will be able to use the passed text ('solar') in shortcodes and other places in the page, like this:

`[documents  category_name="solar" numberposts="-1" orderby="title" order="ASC"]`

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a variable or field that I can simply use within the page text.  I just don't know how to accomplish that.

Here's what I've considered/tried:

1) There are plugins that access the passed variables (e.g. URL params), but that would seem to require nested shortcodes:

`[documents  category_name="[urlparam param="topic" default="home-energy-savings"/]" numberposts="-1" orderby="title" order="ASC"]`

That doesn't work, and I'm not aware of any way to accomplish that.

**Added:** The Shortcode API documentation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets explains that the shortcode parser *cannot* handle square brackets within an attribute.  Unfortunately, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

If that won't work, The question is now - Is there some way within the page content of presenting a shortcode string that has been modified based on a query variable?
**EndAdded**

2) Using a filter to add the variable allows me to access the variable within a page template (e.g. page.php), but I want to use the value within the page itself.

3) Plugins to allow PHP snippets within a page or post.  This seems to be generally discouraged.  It's also complex, and the page itself (which may be used by non-coders) would get hard to use.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: did you try using `$_GET`?

Comment: Yes, but I think that leaves me in the same place.  I can access the variable within a template file (like page.php), but I want to use it within the page text itself.

Comment: Your suggestion led me to further research.  What I found doesn't solve the problem, but it adds more information.  I'll update the original post with what I found.

Answer (score 0):

add_shortcode('cat', 'get_name');

function get_name() {

return '[category_name='.$_GET['topic'].' numberposts="-1" orderby="title" order="ASC"]';

}

or echo do_shortcode('[category_name='.$_GET['topic'].' numberposts="-1" orderby="title" order="ASC"]'); // instead of return.

Should work as snippet function. then use it as [cat] shortcode

Answer (score 0):

In addition, remember to sanitize your $_GET variable. Here's an example in the context of a simple shortcode to display a query variable within the page text, with reference to where I took the sanitizing code from:

```
//[query_string label="" class="" var=""] shortcode
function query_string_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

//Create an array of default values for attributes. These don't have to be blank. If specified as attributes in the shortcode, those values will be used instead.
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'label' => '',
    'class' => '',
    'var' => '',
), $atts );

//Create variables from atts/defaults
$label = $a['label'];
$class = $a['class'];
/*
* 1. Check if the variable is set
* 2. If so, sanitize the input for security (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351292/sanitize-get-query-var-url-parameters)
* 3. Set the variable
*/
$var = ( isset( $_GET[$a['var']] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[$a['var']] ) : '';

if(!empty($label)) { 
    $label = "<b>$label</b>";
}

if(!empty($var)) { 
    $html = '<span class="pt-query ' . $class . '">' . $label . $var . '</span>';
    return $html;
}

return;
}

add_shortcode( 'query_string', 'query_string_shortcode' );
```